# Does this "half-line" convexity imply full convexity?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, convex-analysis, examples-counterexamples, functional-inequalities

Let  $g:\mathbb R \to [0,\infty)$ be a  function satisfying $g(0)=0$, which is strictly increasing on $[0,\infty)$, and strictly decreasing on $(-\infty,0]$.

Suppose that $$g(tx+(1-t)y) \le tg(x) + (1-t)g(y)$$ holds for every $t \in [0,1]$ and every $x,y$ such that $x+y \le 0$.

> Is $g$ convex on all $\mathbb R$?

The assumption clearly implies that $g|_{(-\infty,0]}$ is convex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a $g$ need not be convex. Consider
$$g(x) = \begin{cases}\quad - x &\text{if } x \leqslant 0, \\ \log (1+x) &\text{if } x \geqslant 0. \end{cases}$$

Since $g(-x) \geqslant g(x)$ for all $x \geqslant 0$, this function satisfies the hypothesis, but on $[0,\infty)$ it is strictly concave.

Comment: Thank you. Can you please elaborate on why your example satisfies the hypothesis? I am having trouble verifying $g(tx+(1-t)y) \le tg(x) + (1-t)g(y)$ when $y \le -x <0 < x$ and $tx+(1-t)y \in [y,0]$.

Comment: When $z = tx + (1-t)y \in [y,0]$, then we have $$g(z) = -z = t\cdot (-x) + (1-t)\cdot (-y) \leqslant tg(x) + (1-t)g(y)$$ because $-x < g(x)$ for $x > 0$.

Comment: Thank you. This is a nice answer. I guess the geometric intuition was to choose something, which when you get further away from zero, increases more slowly on the right side then the left side? Also, do you think that it would be possible to "smoothen" this example, say to obtain a $C^1$ function with the same property, which is not convex?

Comment: Yes, that was the geometric idea. If we have $g(-x) \geqslant g(x)$ for $x > 0$, then the secant between $y$ and $x$ where $y \leqslant -x$ has negative or zero slope, so we are safe on $[0,x]$. And since $g(x) \geqslant g(0)$ the secant remains above the secant from $y$ to $0$, so all is well on $[y,0]$ too. We can make it smooth too, but then $g$ can't be strictly convex on all of $[0,\infty)$. Take for example $g(x) = x^2$ for $x \leqslant 1$, and make a smooth transition to something concave and increasing.